# Second JavaScript function is not working with form-tag

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an issue when using javascript with form tag 
when I remove `<form>` all the functions works great, but when I retype It the second function doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('../db.php');
require_once('operationsAPI.php');
?>
<html>
<head><title>::family card::</title><meta charset='utf-8'>
<script>
    function beneficial_status(str) {
        if (str != 'father_info') {
            document.getElementById('father_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('father_health_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_health_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('father_health_note').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_health_note').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('father_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('father_health_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_health_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('father_health_note').removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('father_health_note').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
        }
    }

    function wife_status(str) {
        if (str != 'mother_info') {
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('wife_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="get">
<?
$table = hc_empty_family_info_table();
echo '<table align="center" border="1" dir="rtl">';
foreach($table as $values)
{
echo $values;
}
?>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

any reason for this ? ... and what is the solution ?

Comment: Is this all of your code?  Do you have anything in your form tags, and do you close your form tags?

Comment: off topic: why so many same document.getElementById... Why don't you just assign it to a variable?

Comment: no it's a part of it ,I have just one form tag , and yes I close it ..

Comment: Do you call these functions anywhere?  Don't you think we'd need to see how you actually use them to diagnose them?

Comment: I agree with ChrisWillard. Also do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @AlexShilman I don't know how to do it in another way , I am not an expert in javascript :( .

Comment: @ChrisWillard yes I called it from a php function , there is no problem form the code it self .. the problem appear when using form tag with it .

Comment: @user2930653 like this: var father = document.getElementById('father_status');
father.setAttribute('class', 'test');
father.setAttribute('style', 'color:yellow');

Comment: @AlexShilman  thanks for that I get it now :) , You can view all the code now .

Comment: @user2930653 try closing the </table> tag inside of your form

Comment: Shouldn't the `</form>` and `</table>` tag be switched? table is started by the php script inside the form tag, but closed outside of it.

Comment: @AlexShilman I did it now but nothing changed ..

Comment: @user2930653 what is in your $table variable? array of <tr><td>data</td></tr>

Comment: You say you're using the function in the `<form>` tag, but you don't show that in the code. Please show the version that has the problem.

Comment: yes the function return the array of tr and td , and I give each tag in it an id and I called the JS function from it with onchange event ..
as the following :
` $tvalue = "
 <select name=$field_name->name style='width:100%' onchange='beneficial_status(this.value)'>
 <option></option>
        <option>values</option>
</select>"; `

Comment: Could you right click on the form and inspect element, and then copy and paste the output here>

Comment: @AlexShilman
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<table align="center" border="1" dir="rtl">
<tr><td>status</td>
 <td><select name=hc_beneficial_current_status style='width:100%' onchange='beneficial_status(this.value)'>
    <option></option>
             ...
 </select></td></tr>
 <tr><td>health : </td><td>
 <select id='father_health_status' name=hc_father_health_status style='width:100%'>
    <option></option>
          ...
 </select></td></tr>
 <tr><td>notes : </td><td><textarea id='father_health_note' name=hc_father_health_notes style='width:100%'></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

Comment: where are your option values. I need to see the actual html it renders.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are out of order, you need to close your table before you close your form.  Try this:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="get">
<?
 $table = hc_empty_family_info_table();
 echo '<table align="center" border="1" dir="rtl">';
 foreach($table as $values)
 {
 echo $values;
 }
?>
<!-- these two tags are switched -->
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of JavaScript function "wife_status" the same of HTML element id , changing the name of function or element id will solve the problem . replace "wife_status" function with the following

```
 function wife_status(str) {
        if (str != 'mother_info') {
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("style", "background:#dddddd;width:100%;");
        } else {
            document.getElementById('wife_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').removeAttribute("disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_status').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementById('wife_health_note').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
        }
    }
```